# Prove that a product of Borel algebras is a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-sets, separable-spaces

I was working on the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843076/product-of-borel-algebras-is-borel-algebra-of-the-product) and the very last step in my proof required the following:

> If $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are separable metric spaces, then $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \mathcal{B}(X_i)$ is a sigma algebra.

How do I show this? I'm asking a new question because this short claim is much simpler than what I originally asked. I no longer need people to answer the original complicated question, just this simpler and weaker statement. At the same time, I want to leave the other question available on its own to help people in the future who are looking for the full problem.

Comment: You rare confused about definitions and notations. Product of sigma algebras $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ is **defined ** as the sigma algebra generated by sets of the form $A\times B$ where $A \in \mathcal F$ and $B \in \mathcal G$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That's not the definition my problem is using. This is a direct product, i.e. it is $\{A_1 \times \dots \times A_n : A_i \in \mathcal{B}(X_i)\}.$

Comment: Your family is not  a sigma algebra. If you want to prove that the Borel sigma algebra on a finite product is the product of the Borel sigma algebras you have to use my definition of the product sigma algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove this. $\mathbb R^{2} \setminus [(0,1) \times (0,1)]$ cannot be expressed as  a product $A \times B$ for any sets $A$ and $B$. Hence the collection of sets $A \times B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb R$ is not  a sigma algbra.

Comment: Good point. I will assume the problem forgot to mention your definition (otherwise it would be false like you said), in which case I have nothing left to do.